# How to populate a list using the builder pattern in Java

Tags: java, builder

I have this class which has a builder:

```
public class FieldValidationResponse {

  private Integer status;

  private String message;

  private List<FieldValidationError> errors;
  
}
```

I can build a FieldValidationResponse with an individual FieldValidationError like this:

```
private FieldValidationResponse fieldValidationResponse(String responseMessage, String message) {
    return FieldValidationResponse.builder()
        .message(responseMessage)
        .status(400)
        .error(
            FieldValidationError.builder()
                .message(message)
                .build()
        )
        .build();
}
```

Or I could build a FieldValidationResponse  with multiple FieldValidationError like this:

```
private FieldValidationResponse fieldValidationResponse2(String responseMessage, List<String> messages) {
    List<FieldValidationError> fieldValidationErrors = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String message : messages) {
        fieldValidationErrors.add(
            FieldValidationError.builder()
                .message(message)
                .build()
        );
    }

    return FieldValidationResponse.builder()
        .message(responseMessage)
        .status(400)
        .errors(fieldValidationErrors)
        .build();
}
```

I feel that the way I am populating that list of FieldValidationError in the second method using the builder is not the "most elegant" way, I was wondering if I could improve that second method to populate a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can be achieved using stream.

```
  private FieldValidationResponse fieldValidationResponse2(
      String responseMessage, List<String> messages) {

    return FieldValidationResponse.builder()
        .message(responseMessage)
        .status(400)
        .errors(messages.stream().map(this::buildError).collect(Collectors.toList()))
        .build();
  }

  private FieldValidationError buildError(String message) {
    return FieldValidationError.builder().message(message).build();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would add a method to `FieldValidationResponse`'s builder that can take a list of messages and adds a `FieldValidationError` to itself for each one. Something like this (untested pseudo-code):

```java
public FieldValidationResponseBuilder withErrors(List<String> messages) {
    for (String message : messages) {
        this.withError(message);
    }

    return this;
}

public FieldValidationResponseBuilder withError(String message) {
    this.errors.add(
            FieldValidationError.builder()
                .message(message)
                .build());

    return this;
}
```

The you'd use it like this:

```java
    return FieldValidationResponse.builder()
        .message(responseMessage)
        .status(400)
        .withErrors(messages)
        .build();
```

A side benefit is that this also simplifies your first method a little bit.

Comment: This is a very good answer, for this case I can't implement it because the FieldValidationResponseBuilder is autogenerated, if I was the one coding the builder, definitely would follow this approach. Thanks!

Comment: Is it generated using Lombok? If so, you _can_ [add methods to the generated builder](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder#:~:text=This%20includes%20the%20builder%20itself%3A%20If%20that%20class%20already%20exists%2C%20lombok%20will%20simply%20start%20injecting%20fields%20and%20methods%20inside%20this%20already%20existing%20class).

Comment: I also just discovered the [@Singular annotation](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder#singular) that could help here (if you are using Lombok)

Comment: The autogenerated class I mentioned is generated by the API Builder: https://www.apibuilder.io/